# Netlify "build.command" failed for gatsby website

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby, netlify

I've recently updated some plugins on my Gatsby website. It works fine locally but it is failing the deploy on Netlify.
The error I'm getting is:
"build.command" failed - Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): gatsby build.

I'm thinking that some of the plugin updates might be the cause.

Thanks for your help!

***Netlify deploy log:***

```
3:25:55 PM: Build ready to start
3:25:57 PM: build-image version: 53b83b6bede2920f236b25b6f5a95334320dc849
3:25:57 PM: build-image tag: v3.6.0
3:25:57 PM: buildbot version: 8ae026ef4905d9174e416775c6b64aa19950569b
3:25:57 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
3:25:57 PM: Starting to download cache of 835.8MB
3:26:04 PM: Finished downloading cache in 7.766503086s
3:26:04 PM: Starting to extract cache
3:26:22 PM: Finished extracting cache in 17.591359336s
3:26:22 PM: Finished fetching cache in 25.565252333s
3:26:22 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
3:26:23 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
3:26:28 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'public' versus 'public/' in the Netlify UI
3:26:28 PM: Starting build script
3:26:28 PM: Installing dependencies
3:26:28 PM: Python version set to 2.7
3:26:29 PM: Started restoring cached node version
3:26:32 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
3:26:33 PM: v10.23.0 is already installed.
3:26:33 PM: Now using node v10.23.0 (npm v6.14.8)
3:26:33 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
3:26:33 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
3:26:34 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
3:26:35 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
3:26:35 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
3:26:35 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
3:26:35 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
3:26:36 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.8
3:27:00 PM: > sharp@0.26.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp/node_modules/sharp
3:27:00 PM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
3:27:01 PM: info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.0/libvips-8.10.0-linux-x64.tar.br
3:27:04 PM: > sharp@0.26.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/node_modules/sharp
3:27:04 PM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
3:27:05 PM: info sharp Using cached /opt/buildhome/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.10.0-linux-x64.tar.br
3:27:06 PM: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
3:27:06 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
3:27:06 PM: > core-js@3.8.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js
3:27:06 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
3:27:06 PM: > core-js-pure@3.8.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/core-js-pure
3:27:06 PM: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
3:27:06 PM: > gatsby-telemetry@1.7.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
3:27:06 PM: > node src/postinstall.js || true
3:27:06 PM: > gatsby-cli@2.16.2 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/gatsby-cli
3:27:06 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
3:27:07 PM: > gatsby@2.29.2 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby
3:27:07 PM: > node scripts/postinstall.js
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN @tailwindcss/custom-forms@0.2.1 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN paolotodde.com@3.0.0 No description
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
3:27:09 PM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
3:27:09 PM: added 321 packages from 167 contributors, removed 112 packages, updated 208 packages and audited 2568 packages in 32.574s
3:27:11 PM: 173 packages are looking for funding
3:27:11 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
3:27:11 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
3:27:11 PM: NPM modules installed
3:27:11 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
3:27:13 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
3:27:13 PM: Installing Go version 1.12
3:27:13 PM: unset GOOS;
3:27:13 PM: unset GOARCH;
3:27:13 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme_cache/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
3:27:13 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme_cache/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
3:27:13 PM: go version >&2;
3:27:13 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme_cache/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
3:27:13 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
3:27:13 PM: Installing missing commands
3:27:13 PM: Verify run directory
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:15 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
3:27:15 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ❯ Version
3:27:15 PM:   @netlify/build 8.0.0
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ❯ Flags
3:27:15 PM:   deployId: 5fe9f9033720d60008993f0a
3:27:15 PM:   mode: buildbot
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ❯ Current directory
3:27:15 PM:   /opt/build/repo
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ❯ Config file
3:27:15 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ❯ Context
3:27:15 PM:   production
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:15 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
3:27:15 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:15 PM: ​
3:27:15 PM: $ gatsby build
3:27:18 PM: success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.413s
3:27:19 PM: success load plugins - 0.923s
3:27:19 PM: success onPreInit - 0.037s
3:27:19 PM: success delete html and css files from previous builds - 0.007s
3:27:19 PM: success initialize cache - 0.005s
3:27:19 PM: success copy gatsby files - 0.043s
3:27:19 PM: success onPreBootstrap - 0.021s
3:27:19 PM: success createSchemaCustomization - 0.035s
3:27:20 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
3:27:20 PM: success source and transform nodes - 0.793s
3:27:20 PM: success building schema - 0.374s
3:27:20 PM: info Total nodes: 267, SitePage nodes: 2 (use --verbose for breakdown)
3:27:20 PM: success createPages - 0.005s
3:27:20 PM: success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
3:27:20 PM: success createPagesStatefully - 0.092s
3:27:20 PM: success Cleaning up stale page-data - 0.001s
3:27:20 PM: success update schema - 0.017s
3:27:20 PM: success onPreExtractQueries - 0.000s
3:27:21 PM: success extract queries from components - 0.502s
3:27:21 PM: success write out redirect data - 0.001s
3:27:21 PM: vips_value_hash: no case for NULL
3:27:21 PM:     type 64, gchararray
3:27:21 PM:     generic 53, GParamString
3:27:21 PM: vips_value_hash: no case for 0.000000
3:27:21 PM:     type 60, gdouble
3:27:21 PM:     generic 109, GParamDouble
3:27:21 PM: vips_value_hash: no case for FALSE
3:27:21 PM:     type 20, gboolean
3:27:21 PM:     generic 76, GParamBoolean
3:27:21 PM: vips_value_hash: no case for ((VipsAccess) VIPS_ACCESS_RANDOM)
3:27:21 PM:     type 81740352, VipsAccess
3:27:21 PM:     generic 80, GParamEnum
3:27:21 PM: vips_value_hash: no case for FALSE
3:27:21 PM:     type 20, gboolean
3:27:21 PM:     generic 76, GParamBoolean
3:27:22 PM: ​
3:27:22 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:22 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
3:27:22 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
3:27:22 PM: ​
3:27:22 PM:   Error message
3:27:22 PM:   Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): gatsby build
3:27:22 PM: ​
3:27:22 PM:   Error location
3:27:22 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
3:27:22 PM:   gatsby build
3:27:22 PM: ​
3:27:22 PM:   Resolved config
3:27:22 PM:   build:
3:27:22 PM:     command: gatsby build
3:27:22 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
3:27:22 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
3:27:22 PM: Caching artifacts
3:27:22 PM: Started saving node modules
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving node modules
3:27:22 PM: Started saving build plugins
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving build plugins
3:27:22 PM: Started saving pip cache
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving pip cache
3:27:22 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
3:27:22 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
3:27:22 PM: Started saving rust cargo bin cache
3:27:22 PM: Finished saving rust cargo bin cache
3:27:22 PM: Started saving go dependencies
3:27:23 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
3:27:23 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:27:23 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
3:27:23 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
3:27:23 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m26.932707149s
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "analyze:lint": "eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js .",
        "analyze:prettier": "prettier --list-different \"**/*.{css,js,jsx,json,md}\"",
        "analyze": "npm run analyze:lint && npm run analyze:prettier",
        "fix:lint": "eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js . --fix",
        "fix:prettier": "prettier --write \"**/*.{css,js,jsx,json,md}\"",
        "fix": "npm run fix:lint && npm run fix:prettier",
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "develop": "gatsby develop --open",
        "dev": "npm run develop",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
        "gatsby": "^2.29.2",
        "gatsby-image": "^2.8.0",
        "gatsby-image-background-slider": "0.0.4",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.17",
        "gatsby-plugin-hotjar": "^1.1.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-layout": "^1.7.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.4.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "3.2.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^3.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.7.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.11.2",
        "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.9.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.3.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader": "^1.0.4",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.29",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.9.0",
        "postcss": "^8.2.1",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "16.13.1",
        "react-helmet": "6.0.0",
        "react-intersection-observer": "^8.26.2",
        "react-player": "^2.0.1",
        "react-select": "^3.1.0",
        "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
        "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "0.2.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
        "cssnano": "4.1.10",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-loader": "3.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-eslint": "2.0.8",
        "prettier": "2.0.5",
        "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
    },
    "keywords": [
        
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: using netlify's CLI solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of issue is related to mismatching versions of Node between your local environment and Netlify's one since all your packages are installed in `node_modules` based on your Node version and Netlify's does the same so, there are a couple of things you can do to fix it:

- Reverse your last changes of `package-lock.json` or `yarn-lock.json` to get the previous working version. Once it's done, remove your `node_modules` folder and reinstall your dependencies again.
- Setting the same version of Node in both environments; you can use `node -v` locally to get your working version there (assuming that is building properly in your local machine) and [manage the build dependencies](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript) to set the same version in Netlify's side.
- Force the manual upgrade of the dependencies by running:

  ```
  yarn upgrade gatsby-plugin-manifest@latest gatsby-plugin-sharp@latest
  ```
- Test the local environment by using `netlify-cli` will be helpful to check where the issue is located

Comment: Thanks again @Ferran Buireu

Comment: Has your issue been solved @Paolo_T ? If so, please consider accepting/upvote the answer to close the topic.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The error keeps coming after upgrading to Tailwind v2.
I've run:

`npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`

Answer (score 2):

Fix:
`yarn upgrade gatsby-plugin-manifest@latest gatsby-plugin-sharp@latest`

How I got here:

- Found a [post on Netlify forums from the OP](https://answers.netlify.com/t/build-command-failed-after-upgrading-tailwind/29090/6) - Netlify states that this is related to the VIPS dependency, outside of Netlify's control.
- Found GH Issue on what's the issue for the VIPS dependency [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/29041).
- From those comments, see that the fix is to upgrade the two packages above.

P.S. I also tried changing/upgrading my Node version, as an answer suggested, but that didn't work.

Comment: Spent hours trying all the different suggestions. Upgrading manifest worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Delete **.cache** folder or run `gatsby clean`.